# How to plot 2D Voronoi grid on 3D axes, within bounds?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a straightforward function to plot a Voronoi diagram, which works nice when plotting on 2D axes. However, when I plot the 2D grid on a plane on 3D axes, it overflows.

[image: Nice 2D Hexagonal grid]

[image: Overflowing 3D Hexagonal grid]

Here is the code:

```
function plotHexGrid(X, Y, m, n)

  f1 = figure       
  [XV YV] = voronoi(X(:),Y(:)); 
  plot(XV,YV,'b-');
  axis([1 m 1 n])

  f2 = figure     
  Z = ones(size(XV));
  plot3(XV,YV,Z,'b-');
  axis([1 m 1 n 0 10])    

  saveas(f1,'hexgrid2D.jpg');
  saveas(f2,'hexgrid3D.jpg');
end
```

So I would like to have the grid shown only within the axes boundaries and hide the overflow. I have not been able to find any solutions using Google, so I only tried the following, however without success:

```
xlim([1, n]);
ylim([1, m]);
```

UPDATE:

I have the following values for X, Y, m and n:

```
X = [0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487;
0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487;
0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487;
0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487;
0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487;
0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487;
0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487;
0    3.4641    6.9282   10.3923   13.8564   17.3205   20.7846   24.2487];

Y =  [0     2     0     2     0     2     0     2;
4     6     4     6     4     6     4     6;
8    10     8    10     8    10     8    10;
12    14    12    14    12    14    12    14;
16    18    16    18    16    18    16    18;
20    22    20    22    20    22    20    22;
24    26    24    26    24    26    24    26;
28    30    28    30    28    30    28    30];

m = 20;
n = 20;
```

Comment: Can you add the X, Y, m and n values?

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion @macduf

Comment: Well, works fine on Mac R2014b even without the `xlim` and `ylim`. You may want to try it on a different system/version than yours. Seems like some kind of a graphical bug... Alternatively, you can report it to TheMathWorks.

Comment: btw, do you know that you can rotate the first figure to have a 3D version of the diagram?

Comment: Ok yeah seems like a bug then. I use R2014a on Windows. Thanks for your help anyways! 
I was aware of the rotation possibility :) this was just the part of the figure necessary to show my problem, I am adding other 3D objects.

Comment: @macduf, If you want, you could answer the question so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided code works fine on a Mac R2014b, even without the `xlim` and `ylim` bits. You may want to try it on a different system/version than yours. Seems like some kind of a graphical bug... Alternatively, you can report it to TheMathWorks.

You may also want to rotate the 2-D figure in order to have a 3-D version of the diagram (using `rotate` or with a mouse).